# Using pinescript 5 how can I mark the 3:45am candle, preferably with a shape ontop or beneath like a diamond or star something?

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5, pine-script-v4, candlesticks

I just want to know how I can mark a candle that opened on a specific time.

For example:

We have a 3:45am candle that's marked with a diamond.

Appreciate the help :)

I have tried on my own and tried finding a solution but I'm new to pinescript (and coding in general) so I'm kind of lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `hour` and `minute` built-in variables.

```
is_345 = (hour == 3) and (minute == 45)
plotshape(is_345, style=shape.diamond)
```